# Colorbar height is too large and overlapping figure title

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, colorbar

I have a three-dimensional density distribution and create a figure with two subplots. One of the XY plane and one of the YZ plane. For both figures I want a correct `colorbar` and for some reason the XY plane `colorbar` is perfect and the YZ plane `colorbar` is too big and overlaps the figure title. See below for my code and an image of result. EDIT: added functioning example at bottom

```
%// Data slice in the XY plane
    subplot(1,2,1)
    h=slice(xi,yi,zi,density,[],[],0);
    set(h,'edgecolor','none');
    caxis([-8,-2])
    colormap(jet);
    c = colorbar;
    c.Label.String = 'Density in log 10 scale';
    view(2)
    daspect([1 1 1])
    xlabel('X-axis [km]')
    ylabel('Y-axis [km]')
    zlabel('Z-axis [km]')
    title_orbit = ['Mg sputtering in orbital plane at orbit angle ',is];
    title({title_orbit,''})

%// Data slice in the YZ plane
    subplot(1,2,2)
    g=slice(xi,yi,zi,density,0,[],[]);
    set(g,'edgecolor','none');
    caxis([-8,-2])
    colormap(jet);
    d = colorbar;
    d.Label.String = 'Density in log 10 scale';
    view(90,0)
    daspect([1 1 1])
    xlabel('X-axis [km]')
    ylabel('Y-axis [km]')
    zlabel('Z-axis [km]')
    title_perp = ['Mg sputtering in perpendicular plane at orbit angle ',is];
    title({title_perp,''})
```

[image]

For those who want a working example for trying to fix it, see code below.

```
% Create data with similar structure as original
x = linspace(-100,100,100);
y = linspace(-100,100,100);
z = linspace(-100,100,100);
[xg,yg,zg] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
density = rand([100,100,100]);

% Plot data
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
h=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,[],[],0);
set(h,'edgecolor','none');
colormap(jet);
c = colorbar;
view(2)
daspect([1 1 1])

subplot(1,2,2)
g=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,0,[],[]);
set(g,'edgecolor','none');
colormap(jet);
c = colorbar;
view(90,0)
daspect([1 1 1])
```

Comment: I take back my previous comment, the issue is with the second `view()` call. If you set it the same as the first (or comment it out) the colorbars behave appropriately. I do still recommend that you [submit a bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/) to MathWorks with a **functioning** example.

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the tip I will contact them, but do you know a solution in the mean time? Because a bug fix might take a while

Comment: Every alternative I can think of exhibits the same behavior once `view(90, 0)` is executed, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried changing the figure's renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a possible workaround, first get the color data from each slice, then use `imagesc` or `imshow`to plot that slice data. Using your example:

```
h=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,0,[],[]);
H=get(h,'CData');
...
g=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,0,[],[]);
G=get(g,'CData');
...
```

Then open a new figure and use `imagesc` or `imshow`:

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(H); colormap(jet); colorbar


subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(G); colormap(jet); colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: I can't check right now because I don't have Matlab on this PC. But I noticed that 'h=slice' and 'g=slice' are the same but in my example they are different planes and that is why I need 'view(2)' and 'view(90,0)'. So I am not quite sure if this is solution because I dont see view in your code (might be ...) and it is the same plane for h and g. I will check on monday

Comment: This is indeed a solution, however it messes with my script quite significantly because I use it to make a video. Do you know a solution without starting a new figure?

Comment: there shouldn't be a problem. if you just do everything in a series without a new figure only the `imagesc`part will be displayed.  Just ignore the `figure` command and place the `imagesc` part in the right places in each part of the subplot.

Comment: this is my code now and I get two figures, with only one figure call. Sorry for the mess but copy paste should work because every line has ; at the end.        

x = linspace(-100,100,100);
y = linspace(-100,100,100);
z = linspace(-100,100,100);
[xg,yg,zg] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
density = rand([100,100,100]);

h=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,[],[],0);
set(h,'edgecolor','none');
H=get(h,'CData');
g=slice(xg,yg,zg,density,0,[],[]);
set(g,'edgecolor','none');
G=get(g,'CData');

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(H);
colormap(jet);
c = colorbar;
    
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(G);
colormap(jet);
c = colorbar;